# How to access custom function of window object in a content script for firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have a simple content script

```
function main(){
    //var x = window.getCustomFunctionHere;
    //var y = window.getCustomFunctionHere();
    console.log("a");
    console.log(window);
    console.log("b");
    browser.runtime.sendMessage(["test", x]);
  }
main();
setInterval(main, 10*1000);
```

in the `window` that is printed to the conosle, I see it contains `getCustomFunctionHere()` and likewise, if I open the web-dev console and put in `window.getCustomFunctionHere()` it is returning the proper result.  But, when I execute this script, if I uncomment `var y` I get the error:

```
TypeError: window.getCustomFunctionHere not a function
```

What am I missing? I need to execute this custom function the webpage contains and it will return a string which I will then send to the main browser extension via `browser.runtime.sendMessage`

Comment: It's probably added later